# Migration from crystal reports 8 to crystal reports 2008

Tags: crystal-reports, migration

How to migrate Crystal Reports 8.0 to Crystal Reports 2008?

The crystal reports which had stored procedures of 8.0 are not executing in 2008, 
can anyone help?

We are using Seagate Crystal reports 8 and want to migrate all the 
programs to Crystal Reports 2008 Visual Studio

Can you please explain the pros and cons of this.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have migrated from 8 to XI without issues (just open the report in XI and do a save-as).

Have you tried going to an intermediate version like XI, then opening in 2008 from that version?

Comment: No, I will try and let you know. Thanks alot for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

You'll find some minor syntactical differences in formulas, mostly relating to semi-colons. For example, this works in Crystal 8 and Crystal 8.5 :

```
If {tblMaster.StatusID} In [1,3] Then
    Select {tblLinkTranx.TranxCodeID}
        Case 3 :
            {tblLinkTranx.TranxAmt}
        Case 4 :
            - {tblLinkTranx.TranxAmt}
        Default :
            0;
Else
    0
```

To get the same formula to work in Crystal 9, 10, 11, 11.5 or 2008, you either need to remove the ; or encase the Select clause in brackets.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend making a copy of the reports as a backup.  Reason being that you can go up in versions, but you can't demote versions.

Once you have your backups, simply open the files in Crystal Developer.  It will immediately prompt you that you are using an old report format, providing an OK/cancel prompt for if you want to update the report to the version of Developer you are using.  Crystal has been built to support backwards compatibility.  The upgrade process should be seamless.

Answer (score 1):

If your v8 report uses store()/fetch() to pass data between a main and subreport, you will need to change it to use a Shared variable instead.